# java.lang.ClassCastException for interface On android java

Tags: java, android, interface

I have a Dialog fragment class below with an interface  it throws the following exception:

> **java.lang.ClassCastException: **

```
public class FolderPickerDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        this.listner=(FolderPickerDialog.FolderPickerListner)context;
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    public interface FolderPickerListner {
        void onFolderSelected(String path)
    }
}
```

I have implemented the listener  in below class:

```
public class SaveDialog extends DialogFragment implements FolderPickerDialog.FolderPickerListner {

    @Override
    public void onFolderSelected(String path) {
        ic_path.setText(path);
    }

}
```

**My Log Cat**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nanosoft.icstudio.activities.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.nanosoft.icstudio.Dialogs.FolderPickerDialog$FolderPickerListner
at com.nanosoft.icstudio.Dialogs.FolderPickerDialog.onAttach(FolderPickerDialog.java:43)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1231)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:107)
```

Answer (score 1):

What the error says is that in this line:

```
this.listner=(FolderPickerDialog.FolderPickerListner) context;
```

you try to cast `context` which is `MainActivity`'s context to a `FolderPickerDialog.FolderPickerListner` object and this is impossible.

Comment: But the interface is implemented in another  dialogfragment not in an activity.

Comment: The parameter `context` in `onAttach()` is `MainActivity`'s context.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a listener callback into the `FolderPickerDialog` via Lifecycle Event, you could do like the following:

In `FolderPickerDialog`:

```
private FolderPickerListner listener;
...
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        this.listener=(FolderPickerListner)context;
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
```

In Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FolderPickerDialog.FolderPickerListner {

...


}
```

Comment: I have implemented it in another dialogfragment  not in mainactivity

Comment: @Naveed onAttach is called when a fragment is first attached to its context(activity), not attached to another dialogfragment.